Can I withdraw Aruban florins in Aruba using a Scotiabank debit card from Canada?
I will be visiting Aruba and want to withdraw local currency without paying fees if possible.  I will have credit cards but I’d also like to have some cash on hand and I am unable to find a place in Canada where Florins (AWG) are available.
I have a Scotiabank account in Canada with a debit card (works on the Plus and Interlink networks).
From Scotiabank’s website, it seems they have a presence in the Caribbean, and specifically in Aruba they have an “affiliation” with the local Maduro & Curiel’s Bank.  In other countries, I’ve had success withdrawing local currency out of my Canadian account at “partner” ATMs without paying fees.
Can I withdraw Aruban Florins out of my Canadian Scotiabank account at this bank in Aruba?

Apparently the US dollar is widely accepted in Aruba.

Interesting that despite the "affiliation" as linked by the OP above, they are not part of the Global ATM Alliance for waiving ABM fees.

Have you tried contacting your bank? They must know with whom they're affiliated and what fees they charge.

Adding to another comment: there is a fixed relation, 1 AWG = 0.55 USD. This is the reason you cannot get AWG outside of Aruba, simply no demand. All businesses that take cash accept USD and they are used to that, although you might get some variaton on exchange rate and you may get change in florins.

No, it costs US$10 per withdrawal
I decided to find out myself.  The answer is no, Canadian Scotiabank customers cannot do fee-free withdrawals at Maduro and Curiel’s bank in Aruba.  This strange “affiliation” that Scotiabank claims to have does not appear to extend to retail banking.
I tried using an ATM at a branch of the Caribbean Mercantile Bank (CMB) in Oranjestad.  (CMB appears to be the the brand used for Maduro and Curiel’s bank in Aruba).  It accepted my Canadian Scotiabank debit card, and I had the option of withdrawing in Aruban Florins, but with a service fee of US$10.  So, there you have it, data point for anyone who was curious.
For what it’s worth, I did find USD was accepted everywhere, and Visa/Mastercard at most places.  (Amex not as much)
